# ODE system with lower triangular coefficient matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let $v_k$ satisfies the following equation

$\frac{d}{dt} v_k(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}v_k(t)$

with initial data $v_0(t=0)=1$ and $v_j(t=0)=0$.

Notice that the coefficient matrix $A$ of this ODE system (probably infinite dimensional) is a lower triangular matrix with entries one.

I was trying to find an upper bound of $v_k(t)\leq P(t)e^{at}$ with $P$ some polynomial of $t$ (maybe with coefficient depends on $k$ or maybe not) and $a$ a constant that does not depend on $n$.

(This is equivalent to the original question I asked, but to avoid confusion I write the ODE in recursive form.)

Comment: I think you mean $v_i(t)$ instead of $v_k (t) $ in the sum, right? What about the differential equation for $v_0$, is it given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given the system of ODE's 
$$
\frac{dv_k}{dt} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} v_i(t),\qquad k \geq 1,
$$ 
with $v_0(t)$ some integrable function in $[0,\infty)$, with initial condition $v_k(0) = 0 $ for all $k\geq 1$, and $v_0(0)=1$.

Let $||v_0||_t = \int_0^t |v_0(\tau)|d\tau$.

*Claim*. The estimate
\begin{equation}
|v_k(t)| \leq ||v_0||_t + (2^k-k-1)e^t ||v_0||_t,\qquad k \geq 1
\end{equation}
holds for all $t\geq 0$.

*Proof*. By induction in $k$. First note that 
$$
\frac{dv_{k+1}}{dt} = \frac{dv_{k}}{dt} + v_{k},\qquad k\geq 1.
$$
Integrating on both sides, and using the given initial conditions,
$$
v_{k+1}(t)  = v_{k}(t) + \int_0^t v_k(\tau) d \tau,\qquad k\geq 1.
$$
For $k=1$, the inequality obviously holds. For $k\geq 1$,
\begin{align}
|v_{k+1}(t)| &\leq |v_k(t)| + \int_0^t |v_k(\tau)| d\tau \\ \\
&\leq   \left(1 + (2^k-k-1)e^t \right) ||v_0||_t + \int_0^t \left[ 1 + (2^k-k-1)e^\tau  \right] ||v_0||_\tau d\tau \\
&\leq   \left( 1 + 2^k e^t -k e^t - e^t + t + (2^k-k-1)(e^t-1) \right) ||v_0||_t  \\
&\leq   \left( 1 + (2^{k+1}-(k+1)-1) e^t  \right) ||v_0||_t. 
\end{align}
Where I used $t\leq e^t-1$ from the third to last line (and some simplifications).

For the exact solution of the system I got
\begin{equation}
v_k(t) = \int_0^t v_0(\tau) d \tau + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \sum_{m=1}^j \binom{j}{m} \frac{1}{m!} \int_0^t (t-\tau)^m v_0(\tau) d \tau,
\end{equation}
$k\geq 1$, $t\geq 0$. This can be obtained by the Laplace method.

Comment: after you apply Gronwall's inequality, you get an inequality. Why the coefficient of such inequality still satisfies the equality?

Comment: that step is not justified, thanks. I updated with a simpler proof by induction.

Comment: Actually if you are not interested in a tight estimate then a simple argument is: $|v_{k+1}(t)| \leq |v_k(t)| + \int_0^t |v_k(\tau)| d\tau$, implies $|v_{k+1}(t)| \leq (1+t)||v_k||_t \leq e^t ||v_k||_t$, where $||v_k||_t = \sup\limits_{\tau \in [0,t]} |v_k(\tau)|$.  By induction, $|v_{k}(t)| \leq e^{kt} ||v_0||_t$ for $k\geq 1$, $t\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can actually solve the system explicitly to order $t^2$, obtaining
$$ v_1(t) = 1, \;  v_j(t) \ge t + \dfrac{j-2}{2} t^2 \ \text{for}\ j \ge 2, \; t \ge 0$$
(i.e. $v_j(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$ with nonnegative coefficients and lowest-order terms $t + ((j-2)/2) t^2$).  Note also that $v_j(t)$ is the same for all $n \ge j$.
Thus it is impossible to get a bound  that is uniform in $n$: for any fixed $a$ and $t > 0$, $e^{-at} v_j(t) \to +\infty$ as $j \to \infty$.

Comment: sorry, I made some mistakes in the question. I was trying to find $C$ as a polynomial of $t$ that independent of $n$...

Comment: As I said, $v_j(t) \to \infty$ as $j \to \infty$ for fixed $t > 0$, so it can't be done.

Comment: Of course it converges to infinity. But this does not contradict with the upper bound since $v_j(t)e^{-at}\leq C(t)\rightarrow \infty, as t\rightarrow \infty$. It is still possible be done. What I am interested is to prove its growth is strictly less than exponential growth.

Comment: I just noticed you said your bound on $v_k(t)$ could have coefficients **depending on $k$** (but not on $n$).  Well, $v_k(t)$ does not depend on $n$ for $k \le n$, so that makes it trivial: the polynomial can just be $v_k(t)$.

Comment: thanks for your answer, maybe my problem is not well-defined. My original concern is to show $v_k$ is strictly less than exponential growth. I guess I made wrong statement in the question. My fault and sorry.